# Is there a way to backup everything in an app-engine blobstore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

bulkloader.py is very handy.

But as far as I can tell it doesn't appear to fetch items from the blobstore, so you can be left with broken entity relationships if you needed to dump/restore your application.

Does anyone know a method for completely backing up their data from app-engine including blobstore data?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you would instantiate a BlobInfoFactory and use BlobInfoFactory.queryBlobInfos.

Then for each blob, you would run BlobstoreService.serve(...) with the BlobKeys returned from the BlobInfos.  You still might end up with broken entity relationships - there's no way to guarantee each blob will end up with the same key it was originally loaded with.  You'll have to account for this in your application.

Comment: Then how should I reference the blobs from Datastore?